# Show empty subform fields in a Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Right now it is weird some of my Subforms in my Form are hidden when there is nou RecordSource while others show (the textfield), it looks ugly since most of the subform fields just appear out of nowhere when searching for a recordset.

I checked all properties and they are identical so i dont know what else to do so that my subform fields show even if the recordsource of the main field is empty.

Comment: can you share screenshot indicating a problem.?

Comment: @Tarun.P not really, basicly lets say i have 2 subforms in a form that has an empty recordset, now in one subform i see the textboxes even when empty, the other subform is simply invisible with all its content but i want both to be visible not only one

Comment: do you have `link Master Fields` and `link Child Fields` set on both the subform? check also the filter on  `Empty Master field`

Comment: @Tarun.P did not really help they are linked and if i do the empty master field filter on OFF then i get the form but on start its filled with a random recordset but i need the fields to be empty

Comment: It seems that in one subform you can add new records (in that one you see empty textboxes) and in the other one you can't (therefore, you see nothing).